# Divs are overlaping after setting display: none of one of their elements

Tags: html, css

I am making a comment section for my project and I've added `display: none` to `answear__avatar` on `max-width: 980px` and after that those divs are overlaping each other. How do I stop them from overlapping?

Here's my code:

```css
 .answear__wraper {
  margin-bottom: 10px; }

.answear__answear, .answear__answear--dissucsion {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; }

.answear__answear {
  width: 100%; }

.answear__answear--dissucsion {
  width: 89.4%;
  float: right;
 }

  @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .answear__answear--dissucsion {
      width: 95%; } }

.answear__avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .answear__avatar {
      display: none; } }

.answear__content {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<div class="answear_container">
    <div class="answear__wraper">
        <div class="answear__answear">
            <div class="answear__avatar"><img src="images/user0.jpg" class="image__lg" /></div>
            <div class="answear__content">
                <div class="answear__user">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="answear__answear--dissucsion">
            <div class="answear__avatar"><img src="images/user0.jpg" class="image__lg" /></div>
            <div class="answear__content">
                <div class="answear__user">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `visibility: hidden;` the element will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout.

By using `display: none;` the page will be displayed as if the element is not there.